# Python 2.7 Mathematical operations on output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm quite new to python and currently I'm stuck with one problem. I could do this in BASH, but I'd like to learn python.
I need to do math operations on output from command executed on remote server.

```
if argument == "hosts":
    output = []
    output.append(os.popen("ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=40 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s cat /home/rb6873/oraclevm | cut -d\| -f3 | cut -d\= -f2 " % host).read().rstrip('\n'))
    print(host)
    for row in output:
        print(row)
```

And now I don't know what to do next. I was trying to find solution, but I failed.

In this case output is ['50\n100\n75'], and it's type is list. This is only example, length of this output will vary on different servers.

What I want to do is to do simple math - summarize strings/lines from this output.

Can someone please tell me how to solve my problem or at least point me in right direction?

Best regards,
Jan

Comment: Have you tried anything already? You just need to parse this response (integers separated by \n, as far as I see) and sum them up.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried and where do you get stuck? It sounds that you haven't made a honest effort in trying to solve your problem first...

Comment: As you put it into a list, it is a list, claro. summarize strings means: counting the line end characters? ... or splitting on the line end chacaters, interpreting the entries as numbers and summing these up as an example? Please suggest a more concrete question. Thanks (and offer some of the variance across "output" from the server calls you mention)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid your question is best answered with "read a python tutorial". You need to understand the basics of Python's data types, learn how to work with lists, what the standard integer operations are, how to import modules, and how to read the manual on the `math` module, which provides all sorts of goodies above the base 5 arithmetic operations (including exponentiation `**`).

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of these inputs, you'd just (a) replace `read()` in your `popen` call with `deadlines()`, so that each input line becomes an element in your list; and (b) calculate the sum with `sum(int(x) for x in output)`.

```
if argument == "hosts":
    lines = os.popen(...).readlines()
    print(sum(int(x) for x in lines))
```

But you probably won't be able to explain how this works, so this answer doesn't teach you much about working with python; read [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and you'll find it much easier going. **And switch to Python 3 immediately.** Why are you learning an outdated version of the language?